# Declaring a Numeric Function in an Octave/Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, math, octave

The question is as follows:

Implement in Octave the illinois version of the regula falsi method. 
the signature of the function is

```
illinois(
          f,    % a real numeric function
          a,    % left bound of search interval
          b,    % right bound of search interval
          yAcc, % accuracy in the y-dimsension
          nIter % maximum number of iterations
          )
```

hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method#Illinois_algorithm

i like to ask:

How can i input a real numeric function in Matlab function for this question?

For instance say i am searching for roots in x^2-4 between 1 and 3, so it would be function on the GUI should be

```
illinois(x^2-4, 1, 3, 0.1, 1000)
```

How do i tell matlab/octave this 'numeric function' x^2-4 or i am interpreting the question wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at function handles:

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Handles.html

You can define the function using `f=@(x)(x.^2-2)`, pass it to another function using `g(f,1,2,3,4)` and evaluate it like every other function `f(1)`.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm! is this the only solution possible though?

Comment: It's the only solution I could recommend. An alternative is to pass the function as a string and use 'eval', but to sum up only some disadvantages: Strange error messages, hard to debug, the code is difficult to read, no support for private functions, identical variable name collision and a limited syntax because you have to create the full function in one line.